# How does a NativeModule function and are they cached?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, require, built-in

```js
require('http')
console.log(require.cache.http) // undefined
```

I can't find the `http` module in `require.cache` ? How can I detect it was required? I found `process.moduleLoadList` that contains the string `NativeModule http` but don't see any reference to the cached module where is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NativeModule` means it's not cached: it's compiled. It's defined like this,

> NativeModule: a minimal module system used to load the JavaScript core modules found in `lib/**/*.js` and `deps/**/*.js`. **All core modules are compiled into the node binary via `node_javascript.cc` generated by `js2c.py`, so they can be loaded faster without the cost of I/O.** This class makes the `lib/internal/*`, `deps/internal/*` modules and `internalBinding()` available by default to core modules, and lets the core modules require itself via `require('internal/bootstrap/loaders')` even when this file is not written in CommonJS style.

Emphasis added around *"without the cost of I/O"* so no caching needed.

You can find this system in [`lib/internal/bootstrap/loaders.js`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/ecf4114f942bfadfaacc60f7972651166e8e6dae/lib/internal/bootstrap/loaders.js). You can find the [mapping of native modules to source code here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/61a73f80c7f9faf9dd5e74c1fa5613d70297089b/tsconfig.json#L23), but remember they're not read from disk. You can find [`js2c.py`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/tools/js2c.py)

Comment: Thanks, so I can see the function [`compileForInternalLoader`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/ecf4114f942bfadfaacc60f7972651166e8e6dae/lib/internal/bootstrap/loaders.js#L299-L302) returns a singleton for the same module. But here there is nothing that could discard the instance (like `delete require.cache`) as `NativeModule` is not exported, or is there anyway to do that ? Also, I wonder if I can rely on `process.moduleLoadList` as it's not documented. Is there any reason for that ? Is it not stable or could they change this in the future ?

Comment: No you can't do that. And even if you could do it, it wouldn't make any sense because the module is never loaded from javascript source. On compilation they have a build script that turns javascript source into a big string that gets baked into the binary. The only thing that happens when you say `require('http')` is a string that already exists in the binary is parsed and eval'd.